# Syntax issues sn not adding to email string variable for Set-ADUser script

Tags: powershell, syntax, active-directory

when I use the following script

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=ADMIN,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $email = $user.givenName + '.' + $user.sn + '@emailserver.com'
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname -EmailAddress $email
}
```

The result of this is firstname.@emailserver.com  it appears to be skipping the $user.sn.

Am I typing this correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$user.surname` instead of `$user.sn`, as there is no such property `sn` in the object returned by `Get-ADUser` by default.

[image]

Comment: That's weird, the properties box in AD itself shows sn as a field. Anyways, your edit worked thanks.

Comment: I know it does, however Get-ADUser loads only a handful by default (probably performance reasons). If you'd expand your command with `-Properties sn` you would get it as well, or `-Properties *` would give you all AD attributes. But hey, surname is already there :)